# Coalesce in where clause removing too many rows

Tags: sql, coalesce

I have two tables that each hold the same fields but from two different data entry systems, which I've joined using UNION so have no true duplicate records. However some records have been entered on both systems with slightly different data, and I need to remove rows where they were entered with null values on one system but have values on the other - I've used COALESCE and in 99% of the cases this has worked perfectly. The problem is where there are two rows which both have genuine nulls (see below for sample data):

```
PersonID    Location1   Location2           Date
1           NULL            NULL            2016-05-01
1           NULL            NULL            2014-10-01
1           Home            Home            2016-05-01

2           HospitalA       HospitalB       2016-07-23
2           NULL            NULL            2016-07-23

3           HospitalA       HospitalA       2014-12-19
3           HospitalB       HospitalB       2016-08-16
```

If the dates are the same, I only want the row with location values but if the dates are different I want one row for each date even if one of the dates has NULL as the location - PersonID 1 has two rows, one NULL location dated 2014-10-01 and one with location dated 2016-05-01; PersonID 2 has one row with a location dated 2016-07-23 and PersonID 3 has two rows both with locations and different dates.

The query I'm using is

```
select *
from 
(select PersonID, Location1, Location2, Date
from tablea
union
select PersonID, Location1, Location2, Date
from tableb) as PID
where Location1 = coalesce(Location1,'')
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers

Comment: If Location1 is null, the row will not be returned. If Location1 has a non-null value, the row will be returned.

Comment: Add sample data for both tables, and the expected result. (As well formatted text.)

Comment: What does that table represent?  `tablea`, `tableb`, a composite?  Something else?  Also, what is your expected output?

Comment: The sample data I've given can be in either table (tablea or tableb) or in both depending on when the data was entered. Unfortunately there's no date entered field otherwise I could use a max on that. Tablea and table b just represent the two tables in the warehouse, one old system and one new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `UNION` lists the content of the two tables one after the other, so each row only has the fields of its original table. This means that `where Location1 = coalesce(Location1,'')` is checking a field against itself.

To achieve what you want you will probably need an aggregation on the result of your `UNION`

```
select  PersonID, max(Location1), max(Location2), Date
from    (
          select  PersonID, Location1, Location2, Date
          from    tablea
          union all
          select  PersonID, Location1, Location2, Date
          from tableb
        ) as PID
group by PersonID, Date
```

Comment: Good explanation. You can use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` here to spare the DBMS some work, though.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner You're right, I edited my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: That works perfectly and is far simpler than the convoluted things I was trying. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a kind of usage of COALESCE applied as an aggregate operator in a GROUP BY :

SELECT PersonID, Date, COALESCE(location1), COALESCE(location2)
  FROM your-union-here
GROUP BY PersonID,Date

However, I do not know whether SQL supports COALESCE in this form of aggregate function.

And even if it does work, you still need to carefully inspect what happens if some person has two distinct locations on the same day (COALESCE will necessarily retain only one of them).

Comment: One would typically use `MIN` or `MAX` for the aggregation here.

Answer (score 0):

One row per person and date translates to `GROUP BY person, date` in SQL.

```
select 
  personid, 
  max(location1) as location1,
  max(location2) as location2,
  date
from 
(
  select personid, location1, location2, date
  from tablea
  union all
  select personid, location1, location2, date
  from tableb
) as pid
group by personid, date;
```